# How to make a simple touch screen test application?

Tags: android, touch, screen

I want to make a simple touch screen test application like Samsung Device Diagnostic Tool.

A screenshot from Samsung Device Diagnostic Tool: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KgKW.jpg

I'm not very familiar with Android App Development. Which way would you suggest me to make a simple application like the tool I mentioned above?

Comment: find solution??

Answer (score 1):

The development of this application easy matter. You need to understand:

How to get the coordinates of click.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)(event.getX()/tileSize);
    int y = (int)(event.getY()/tileSize);
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        map[x][y] = true;
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    }
return false;
}
```

Override method onDraw, to draw rectangles.

```
  private void init(){
  tileSize = 10;

  paint1 = new Paint();
  paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  paint1.setStrokeWidth(10);
  paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

  paint2 = new Paint();
  paint2.setColor(Color.RED);
  paint2.setStrokeWidth(10);
  paint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.onDraw(canvas);
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++){
        Paint p = null; 
        if(map[i][j]){
        p=paint1;
        }else{
        p=paint2;
        }
        canvas.drawRect(i*tileSize, j*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize, paint);
    }

}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide complete solution?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I also had to make this screen test in my app. So I had figured a solution. I am taking an array of `RectF` i.e. `ArrayList<RectF> arr = new ArrayList<>()` and drawing this `Rects` in following order :

1. Left vertical line

   ```
   private void drawLeftLine(int width, int height) {
   int leftPoint = 0;
   int topPoint = 0;
   int rightPoint = 100;
   int bottomPoint = 100;

   int maxNoOfRect = height / 100;
   int lastRectHeight = height % 100;

   for (int i = 0; i < maxNoOfRect; i++) {
       arr.add(new RectF(leftPoint, topPoint, rightPoint, bottomPoint));
       topPoint = bottomPoint;
       bottomPoint = bottomPoint + 100;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Top Horizontal line

   private void drawTopLine(int w, int h) {

   ```
   int leftPoint = 0;
   int topPoint = 0;
   int rightPoint = 100;
   int bottomPoint = 100;

   int maxNoOfRect = w / 100;
   int lastRectWidth = w % 100;

   for (int i = 0; i < maxNoOfRect; i++) {
       arr.add(new RectF(leftPoint, topPoint, rightPoint, bottomPoint));
       leftPoint = rightPoint;
       rightPoint = rightPoint + 100;
   }
   arr.add(new RectF(leftPoint, topPoint, rightPoint + lastRectWidth, bottomPoint));
   ```

   }

and similarly; 3. Right vertical line 4. Bottom horizontal line, with the help of collections of `RectF` of size 100.

So, when user touch a point, check whether that co-ordinate lies in any of the `RectF` bounds? If yes, remove that `RectF` from the array.
like :

```
     @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (mOnViewTouchedListener != null)
                mOnViewTouchedListener.onViewTouched();
            Point point = new Point();
            point.x = (int) event.getX();
            point.y = (int) event.getY();
            Log.d("TAG", "point: " + point);

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                if (arr.get(i).contains(point.x, point.y)) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Touch IN");
                    arr.remove(i);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mOnViewTouchedListener != null)
                mOnViewTouchedListener.onViewTouched();
            Log.d("TAG", "ACTION_MOVE");
            Point point1 = new Point();
            point1.x = (int) event.getX();
            point1.y = (int) event.getY();
            Log.d("TAG", "point: " + point1);

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                if (arr.get(i).contains(point1.x, point1.y)) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Touch IN");
                    arr.remove(i);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So, this is the solution for this. Same way the diagonal lines are also drawn.

Diagonal line from top left to bottom right :

```
 private void drawTBDiagonalLine(int w, int h) {

    float height = h;
    float width = w;
    float slope = (height / width);

    float left = 0;
    float top = 0;
    float bottom = 100;
    float right = bottom / slope;

    int maxNoOfRect = h / 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxNoOfRect; i++) {
        arr.add(new RectF(left, top, right, bottom));
        left = right;
        top = bottom;
        bottom = bottom + 100;
        right = bottom / slope;
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution not available.

Comment: No solution available in your git

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I still haven't posted the solution on my github account.

Comment: can you please provide this full class? I really need this for one of my application I can even pay